# Python library for listening to gitlab changes

Tags: python, gitlab

I am in need of a `python` library that provides the facility for `gitlab` events. For a example, I need to run a small python app, with that said library and if any changes happen in the `gitlab`, i need the this python app to react acoordingly.

one eg scenario: If someone commits to a branch (or anywhere in the repository), I need to pull the latest changes.

Is there a `python` library for `gitlab` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `python-gitlab` module:
   https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab

   doc: https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

   and for manage event:
   https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/events.html
2. `pyapi-gitlab` is a python wrapper for the Gitlab API:
   https://github.com/pyapi-gitlab/pyapi-gitlab
3. `python-gitlab3`: Python wrapper for the entire GitLab API: https://github.com/doctormo/python-gitlab3